# Setting values in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter has no effect

Tags: ios, audio, ios7

I'm writing an app that plays audio and I'm trying to get current track information to appear on the lock screen and the control panel. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)setupNowPlayingInfo:(MPMediaItem*)mi
{
    NSArray* keys = @[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyComposer,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyGenre,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

    NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString* key in keys) {
        if ([mi valueForProperty:key]) {
            d[key] = [mi valueForProperty:key];
        }
    }

    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = @0.5;   // TODO:
    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = @1;
    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex] = @(self.currentSongIndex);
    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount] = @(self.songs.count);
    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyChapterNumber] = @0;
    d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyChapterCount] = @0;

    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = d;
}
```

This has no effect. I saw this intriguing line in the documentation for remote control events (which also aren't working for me):

> Your app must be the “Now Playing” app. Restated, even if your app is
>   the first responder and you have turned on event delivery, your app
>   does not receive remote control events until it begins playing audio.

What does my app have to do to become the "Now Playing" app? It's definitely playing audio.

It might be relevant to know that I only need this to work on iOS 7, and I'm using [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup background Audio first

with Audio sessions

```
// Set AVAudioSession
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];

// Change the default output audio route
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                        sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
```